# Constraint using IF statement

Tags: constraints, gams-math

I am using GAMS to solve a network distribution problem and this is my first time using GAMS. I have the following constraint (see Image) which I want to write in gams but keep getting errors. Trying to figure it out using IF statement or any other way to solve it. The variable z is a binary variable, which has been declared already.

Thanks!

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCHXg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need an if statement, but can handle this with dollar conditions.
You can do it with dollar conditions in the equation (as done here), or you could write three separate equations with dollar conditions to define the domain of each equation.

```
E_z(u,v,i).. sum(j, z(u,v,j,i)) - sum(j, z(u,v,i,j)) 
=E= 
0 + 1$(sameas(i,u)) - 1$(sameas(i,v));
```

The sameas operator is documented [here](https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/userguides/mccarl/sameas_and_diag.htm). If your sets have numerical values, it might be cleaner to do a value comparison, e.g. $(i.val = u.val).

Comment: The part "0 +" directly after the "=E=" could even be left out since "1$(sameas(i,u))" will evaluate to 0 if "i" and "u" are not the same, but that's just cosmetics and probably a question of personal taste.

Comment: Yes. I thought making it explicit was clearer.
Personally I would prefer to have three separate equations.

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about conditional expressions in GAMS in the following link:

https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/userguides/userguide/_u_g__cond_expr.html